# Vscode python interactive terminal with shared environment with Jupyternote book

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm new to the vscode, so I wonder if it is possible to have an interactive python terminal with the same environment as a Jupyter notebook. The reason I ask this is I'm a Rstudio user, It is good to have a terminal down below and an area showing the variables I have for current space. I know in vscode I can see what variables I have. And I can have a terminal down below as python, but the problem is they don't share the working space, when I run `a = 1` in Jupyter notebook, and type `print(a)` it will show "NameError: name 'a' is not defined." So is there a way to connect the 2 environments (or space)? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you want: [Python Interactive window](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py).

1. Install Python and Jupyter extension.
2. Read the docs and you can use right-click to open it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response! I can find this option for. py file but not for jupyter notebook, I think it would be better to have an interactive window all the time during I'm writing code and also share the variables and the environment with the jupyter notebook.

Comment: The function is provided by jupyter extension for python files. Why open an interactive window with the same function in the. ipynb file? It seems to be of little use. You can use jupyter notebook directly。